# Can you have multiple delegate methods for the same function

Tags: objective-c

For example, could you have two delegats for MKMapViewDelegate and have them both implement - mapView:sender:viewForAnnotation:annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MKMapView` can only have one delegate at a time. Of course you can switch the delegate when you need to, or you could have the delegate call the other object that you intend to use as a delegate.

But I think this smells of a bad architecture. Ask yourself: Why do you even want more than one delegate? You very probably don't.